# What are the benefits of using the Heroku Mailgun addon vs just going straight through Mailgun api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq, mailgun

I see the pricing tier on Heroku is buckets of cost per month. And on the Mailgun account it's cost per ping.

But, how much of the automation is included on Heroku addon and would it be covered by Redis/Sidekick anyway if I have it running?

Thanks in advance!